# Chrome extension: updates input value and clicks submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, automation, auto-update

Hi I am new to chrome extensions, and need help with the back end. and trying to access the Dom of the currently selected tab. so that I can change the value of the endDatePicker ID to 1 day ahead. eg, from Wednesday 4 may 2016 to Thursday 5 may 2016

and then also click the Submit button (I dont know if you could just run the "checkSubmit(); return false;" method once you have the DOM or not?)

Thanks for the help

the date picker that i am trying to change

```
<input name="endDatePicker" type="text" id="endDatePicker" class="tradeDatePickers hasDatepicker valid" readonly="readonly">
```

the button that needs to be clicked

```
<button type="submit" name="UpdateItemSubmit" class="btn btn-signin btn-text tradeformcommonbtn" value="Update Your Existing Listing" onclick="checkSubmit(); return false;">Update Listing<i class="icon-white icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Here is what I have got so far

manifest.json
        {
      "manifest_version": 2,

```
  "name": "Listing Updater",
  "description": "Update BidorBuy listings",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab","tabs"
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Listing Updater</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Listing Updater</h1>

    <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="inputdate">
<br />
    <button>Update Listings</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function setdate() {
    var date = document.getElementById("inputdate").value;
    document.getElementById("endDatePicker").innerHTML = date;
}

function update() {
checkSubmit();
}

function runTask() {
  setdate();
  update();
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  setTimeout(runTask, 100);
}

function main() {
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  main();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) s.o. is not for posting a requirement. read the docs, try something, show us your attempt and what's not working.

Comment: As someone new to Chrome Extensions, you definitely should read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)

Comment: I have read through that before and under stand what needs to happen i just don't know how to put it all together. Mainly how the content.js gets the info from the the current tab.